# How is std::cin >> std::string implemented?

Tags: c++, string, std, cin, stdstring

In particular, how do the code check if memory for chars should be reallocated? Or how many chars the user entered?
If I wanted to assign a C-string's value to my implementation of a string class I would probably do something like this

```
   String& operator=(String& to, const char *from)
   {
      if((strlen(from) + 1) > to.size) {
        if (to.str != NULL) {
          delete[] to.str;
          to.str = NULL;
        }
        to.size = strlen(from) + 1;
        to.str = new char[to.size];
      }
      strcpy(to.str, from);
      return to;
    }
```

Easy enough. But the operator>> of the std::string is really making me curious.

Comment: The source code to various C++ runtime libraries (say [GNU's libstdc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/)) is available.

Comment: Your code is not exception safe: if the allocate fails, `to.str` points to stale memory. In general, assignments are best implemented in terms of constructions: `T& T::operator=(S from) { T(from).swap(*this); return *this; }` (doesn't work with throwing move assignments, however).

Comment: @DietmarKühl won't "new" throw an exception if allocation fails?

Comment: @Anhil: Exactly. If new does throw an exception, you're left with an object with a bad `to.str`. (You called delete on it, but never assigned it a value!) Dietmar's advice about putting `=` in terms of other constructors (see the copy-and-swap idiom) is good advice, and avoids the trouble with exceptions leaving behind corrupt objects.

Comment: @Anhil: yes, `new char[...]` may throw an exception but you can't recover the value of `to.str` (for a strongly exception safe assignment nothing would change) and you didn't set `to.str`, at least, to a value which avoids double deletion (that is, your code doesn't even provide the basic exception guarantee). That's the whole point of why your code is not exception safe.

Comment: @Thanatos: oh, right. Thanks. I should learn about this copy-and-swap idiom, never seen it before.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: would `if(... && to.str != NULL)` and `to.str = NULL` (after delete) solve the issue?

Comment: @Anhil: You would end up with an implementation which would implement the basic exception safety guarantee. It would classify as exception-safe but I consider an error to implement the basic exception-safety guarantee when the code could be strongly exception-safe, especially when it comes for free (or is even cheaper as is likely the case if you need additional checks otherwise). Check the [exception safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety) definition: you always target the strongest guarantee which can reasonably achieved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fundamentally, the implementation looks something like this (ignoring the fact that both the streams and the string are templates):

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, std::string& value) {
    std::istream::sentry cerberos(in);
    if (cerberos) {
        value.erase();
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it(in), end;
        if (it != end) {
            std::ctype<char> const& ctype(std::use_facet<std::ctype<char> >(in.getloc()));
            std::back_insert_iterator<std::string> to(value);
            std::streamsize n(0), width(in.width()? in.width(): std::string::max_size());
            for (; it != end && n != width && !ctype.is(std::ctype_base::space, *it); ++it, ++to) {
                *to = *it;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    }
    return in;
}
```

A reasonable implementation would probably use an algorithm which would process the content of the stream buffer's buffer segment-wise, e.g., to avoid the repeated checks and calls to `is()` (although for the `std::ctype<char>` it is really just applying a mask to an element of an array). In any case, the input operator wouldn't faff about allocating memory: a typical case "not my job".

Comment: Wow! That code looks really great! Simply put, it loops through the input buffer and inserts chars at the end of the string till space/tab/newline is reached, right?

Comment: @Anhil: Yes. Conceptually, this is how it works although an actual implementation will probably bypass the actual interface of both the stream buffer and the string in some form...

Answer (score 0):

I believe it must use some sort of smart memory allocation management. If you are familiar with c, you would have seen the function `realloc`. My thought is that most container classes in the stl internally use some form of realloc to allocate more memory to themselves.

To to answer your question, the string class is `typedef`'d from another class: `std::basic_string<char>` which is basically an array of char. So internally it has reserved memory that can grow or shrink depending on the user's preferences or needs. And like I mentioned before this memory management is done in a way that is optimal and safe so that information is not lost.

If I were to implement `std::cin >> std::string` it will be in the form of a for loop that iterates through the array of char and assigns a value to each character in the array

Comment: Actually, `std::string` is **not** derived from `std::basic_string<char>`! `std::string` is the same type as `std::basic_string<char>`. `std::string` is a `typedef` or a using alias of `std::basic_string<char>`. Also note that making sure the string is null-terminated is the job of the string class: the input operator is merely a client of that class.